# Android AdSense. Can't see an advertisement in an application

Tags: android, adview

I have a problem with AdSence. I have tried to resolve it the last couple of days but without any good results. I used developers guide but it still empty on the place of banner.

What am I doing in an application. First of all I have added a TableRow object and added AdView to it:

```
    banner = new TableRow(engine);
    banner.setGravity(Gravity.TOP & Gravity.RIGHT);

    adView =  new AdView(engine, AdSize.BANNER, "a14def8xxxxxxxx");
    banner.addView(adView); 
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest(); 
    adView.loadAd(request);
```

Afterwards I just added this "banner" object to the other view. At the end - there is no output there. In case I changed AdView to TextView, just for the proof of concept, it works fine.

The output log:

06-13 18:04:38.476: INFO/Ads(576): Received ad url: <"url": "http://r.admob.com:80/ad_source.php?... >
06-13 18:04:40.406: INFO/Ads(576): onReceiveAd()

The only strange thing for me in log is:

06-13 18:04:40.336: WARN/webcore(576): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout

I haven't found what is it means and is it because of AdSence.

**Update**

I have the class:

```
public class QuestEngine extends Activity {
```

Then I am trying to produce new AdView in method:

```
public IntroView(QuestEngine engine) {
```

That is why in "new AdView" I am using engine object.

Comment: Try `request.setTesting(TESTING_MODE);` before you call `loadAd(..)` so you will always be able to see the ad while debugging your issue.

Comment: I have tried to add this. I have tried to set device too, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: No, it won't fix your problem but it will allow you to easily confirm that it is fixed when you do fix it.  Have you tried removing the `setGravity()` method?  Does it show up then?

Comment: read the [FAQ]. Stackoverflow is not a forum. Updates to your question are made by editing the question, not posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the new AdView declaration to:

```
adView =  new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14def820df0417");
```

The engine object does not contain the context for its dimensions.  The dimensions of the table row are in the Activity context "this"

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are setting your `adView` via `xml/layout file` then do as directed below:-

In your `activity.xml` file insert the following tag where you want your `AdView` to be shown:-

```
<com.google.ads.doubleclick.DfpAdView 
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="/XXXXX/XXXXX"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        />
```

And in your `Activity.java` file write this code in your `onCreate() Method` of the `Activity Life Cycle`:-

```
// Look up the DfpAdView as a resource and load a request.
        adView = (DfpAdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Now if you want to programmatic set the `AdView` in your Activity then follow the steps as directed below:-

Write the following code in your `onCreate() method`,
I am demonstrating for `Fragment`, so write the following code in your `onActivityCreated()Method`.

```
// Create an ad view as a second header for now to meet deadlines
        DfpAdView mAdView=null; //you can also define this as a Global Variable.
        if (mAdView == null) {
            mAdView = new DfpAdView(getActivity(), AdSize.BANNER, "/XXXX/XXXX"); //give your adId incase of XXXX
            iaddHeight= (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); //This code is used to set the height of the addHeight as 50 pixels, which could be used in layout params.

            RelativeLayout fl =new RelativeLayout(this.getActivity());
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams flParams =new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            flParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams para =new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); 
         para.setMargins(0, 0, 0,iaddHeight);

        getListView().setLayoutParams(para);

        this.getActivity().addContentView(fl, flParams);        
        fl.addView(mAdView,flParams);
        }
        mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Hope This can help Any Future users...